# How many times does a Common Lisp compiler recompile?

Tags: compilation, common-lisp

While not all Common Lisp implementations do compilation to machine code, some of them do, including SBCL and CCL.

In C/C++, if the source files don't change, the binary output of a C/C++ compiler will also not change, assuming the underlying system remains the same.

In a Common Lisp compiler, the compilation is not under the user's direct control, unlike C/C++. My question is that if the Lisp source files haven't changed, under what circumstances will a CL compiler compile the code more than once, and why? If possible, a simple illustrative example would be helpful.

Comment: The compiler doesn't compile *files*.  It compiles *code*.  E.g., you can type at the REPL `(compile nil (list 'lambda (list 'x) (list '+ 'x 'x)))`.  There's no file involved at all.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor it's still possible to put code in files, though, and compile from there.

Comment: of course (see my answer), but in that case, some code is read from a file, and the compiled contents are written to another file which can then be loaded.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Ok, if the question is sufficiently ill-posed, maybe deleting it would be a good idea. What is your opinion, of any?

Comment: Based on the opinion of people on #lisp I've flagged this question for deletion. The system won't let me delete, saying it has answers.

Comment: I don't necessarily think it's a *bad* question;  having mistaken assumptions is something that we've all done in the past, and many people have some misconceptions about how compilation works in Common Lisp.  I think this question and its answers may be useful to people in the future.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor well, I'll leave it up to the mods if they decide to delete it. I'm not sure how to unflag a question.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for Stackoverflow. The question is vague, not based on an actual programming problem, no examples are given, ...

Comment: The user is usually guided by the developer INSTALL files or documentation in both C/C++ and CL. In both cases compilation will compile unless you use some sort of tool, eg. make, to not compile files where the object files are newer than the source files.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question is based on some misconceptions.  The compiler doesn't compile files, and it's not something that the user has no control over.  The compiler is quite readily available through the [**compile**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp.htm) function.  The compiler operates on *code*, not on files.  E.g., you can type at the REPL

```
CL-USER> (compile nil (list 'lambda (list 'x) (list '+ 'x 'x)))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X)) {100460E24B}>
NIL
NIL
```

There's no file involved at all.  However, there is also a [**compile-file**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp_fi.htm#compile-file) function, but notice that its description is:

> compile-file transforms the contents of the file specified by
>   input-file into implementation-dependent binary data which are placed
>   in the file specified by output-file.

The *contents* of the file are compiled.  Then that *compiled file* can be [**load**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm)ed. (You can also **load** uncompiled source files, too.)  I think your question might boil down to asking under what circumstances would **compile-file** generate a file with different contents.  I think that's really implementation dependent, and it's not really predictable.  I don't know that your characterization of compilers for other languages necessarily holds either:

> In C/C++, if the source files don't change, the binary output of a
>   C/C++ compiler will also not change, assuming the underlying system
>   remains the same.

What if the compiler happens to include a timestamp into the output in some data segment?  Then you'd get different binary output every time.  It's true that some common scripted compilation/build systems (e.g., **make** and similar) will check whether previous output can be reused based on whether the input files have changed in the meantime.  That doesn't really say what the *compiler* does, though.

Comment: Actually the file compiler compiles files. COMPILE compiles only single functions. See the CLHS documentation of the file compiler.

Comment: Yes, there is a file compiler, described in [3.2.3 File Compilation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bc.htm).  I specifically mentioned **compile-file** to point out that yes, we do typically "compile files", really, it's not the files that are compiled, but the *forms* that are read from the file.  That's really true of most languages, but the internals are exposed more in Common Lisp.

Comment: Right, the point is that many forms have a special meaning when processed by the file compiler and many forms can't be compiled in a similar meaningful way with COMPILE. Thus the file compiler is not just reading through forms and compiling them one by one. There is more to it. The compiler might be a multi-pass compiler creating intermediate files, it might do optimizations on forms after it read all of them, etc. Some compiler actions have file scope, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The rules are pretty much the same, but in Common Lisp, it's not a practice to separate declarations from implementation, so usually you must recompile every dependency to be sure.  This is a shared practical consequence of dynamic environments.

Imagining there was such separation in place, the following are blantant examples (clearly not exhaustive) of changes that require recompiling specific dependent files, as the output may be different:

- A changed package definition
- A changed macro character or a change in its code
- A changed macro
- Adding or removing a `inline` or  `notinline` declaration
- A change in a global type or function type declaration
- A changed function used in `#.`, `defvar`, `defparameter`, `defconstant`, `load-time-value`, `eql` specializer, `make-load-form` generated code, `defmacro` et al (e.g. setf expanders)...
- A change in the Lisp compiler, or in the base image

I mean, you can see it's not trivial to determine which files need to be recompiled.  Sometimes, the answer is "all subsequent files", e.g. changing the `"` (double-quotes) macro-character, which might affect every literal string, or the compiler evolved in a non-backwards compatible way.  In essence, we end where we started: you can only be sure with a full recompile and not reusing fasls across compilations.  And sometimes it's faster than determining the minimum set of files that need to be recompiled.

In practice, you end up compiling single definitions a lot in development (e.g. with Slime) and not recompiling files when there's a fasl as old or younger than the source file.  Many times, you reuse files from e.g. Quicklisp.  But for testing and deployment, I advise clearing all fasls and recompiling everything.

There have been efforts to automate minimum dependency compilation with SBCL, but I think it's too slow when you change the interim projects more often that not (it involves a lot of forking, so in Windows it's either infeasible or very slow).  However, it may be a time saver for base libraries that rarely change, if at all.

Another approach is to make custom base images with base libraries built-in, i.e. those you always load.  It'll save both compilation and load times.

Comment: Hmm, what do you think ASDF and similar is for? `:depends-on` and `:in-order-to` ? https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Common-attributes-of-components.html#Dependencies-1
Lisp projects use build tools like ASDF to describe the dependencies between files and allow to minimize compilation / loading activity.

Comment: "changes that require recompiling specific dependent files, as the output may be different" It's true that such changes would be necessitate recompilation, though not *necessarily* of the whole file. However, there's an (incorrect) premise in the question: **In a Common Lisp compiler, the compilation is not under the user's direct control, unlike C/C++.**  None of this recompilation is automatic, though. A Lisp system doesn't watch for changes to a source file that it once compiled in order to recompile it if the file changes.  It's still up to the *user* to recompile when these things change.

Comment: That's exactly my point, even regarding ASDF that @RainerJoswig mentions.  In the C/C++ world, when you talk about minimizing required compilation, it goes down to precompiled headers and specific .c/.cpp files.  In Lisp, you have to recompile dependent projects, that's the usual granularity.  Also note that this is about file compilation, I don't know of any implementation smart enough that recompiles only certain top-level expressions (that would be really **really** smart).

Comment: @PauloMadeira: not necessarily dependent projects. ASDF let's me specify dependent files and compilation strategies for groups of those file dependencies. Such a tool then plans a minimal compilation. I then have files for package definitions, base utilities, base macros, general code etc. As an example see the ASDF declaration of McCLIM...

Comment: Yes, but now think of a project that depends on McCLIM, directly or not, can you make it recompile only the needed files if McCLIM changes?

Comment: @RainerJoswig, although it justifies answering explaining ASDF a bit for same-module dependencies, I'll upvote such post.

Comment: @PauloMadeira: that's a really good question, but it would not fit well here to explore that.